# In Chrome console, how do you set data you've outputted into console into a local variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, google-chrome-devtools

Does anybody know how to take the last thing (or recent thing) that was outputted by Chrome console into a local variable.

There was a very simple way to do this.

And this makes it quite easy, for example, to navigate through nested data and then taking that navigation into your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how, in case helpful to anybody in the future.

STEP 1: Identify the data you want to put into a variable

[image: Data in console]

STEP 2: Right click on the data and click "Store object as global variable"

[image: Right click]

STEP 3: This new variable will be outputted in the next line. Usually `temp1`

[image: temp1]

STEP 4: Now use the dot notation to navigate through the data.

You can use this variable as you wish; I use dot notation to navigate through the data. This helps in case, I need to navigate through data or array in code and I want to confirm that I am doing it correctly.

[image: Example of navigating through the data]